# Web Application To Customize Virtual Guitar

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm a designer that's learning more of the coding end of things. So... How does one approach coding a web application that allows the user to customize and order a guitar? I'm looking for a quick overview so I can focus on learning and coding specific steps.

My approach is:

1. Creating HTML radio buttons for each group of options, ie. body shape, color, wood type, etc.
2. Use Javascript logic like: if this radio is clicked, all other in the category is false, and display corresponding .png image.
3. Have a submit button and use PHP to put it in a database or send data as an email.

This is my current project. I have the graphics ready to go that lay nicely on top of eachother.

Adding to or changing a part of my approach is greatly appreciated. I am seeking more clarity on what to learn next. This web app is currently 0% coded.

Comment: I don't get it. What is the question? You seem to have it all figured out.

Comment: You came to the right place for advice, but as your question is currently worded, it is too broad. Stack Overflow prefers questions that are definitely answerable. To make your question more answerable, maybe you could list out some possible downsides to your approach and ask if those apply. You could compare two ways of doing one step and ask which is better. Well, not **better**, perhaps ask which is more **effecient**, or more **common**, etc. You don't necessarily have a poor question, you just don't have an eligible question as of now.

Comment: It's obvious that you've put thought and work into this post, and there are definitely good questions to be asked by you about your work so far and work to come, you just need to make those more apparent in the post.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I think what is missing is the code (not written.)

Comment: Even though this is a great question, as it stands it is off-topic for Stackoverflow, and may be better suited if you repost it on one of the sister sites.

Comment: My question is too broad, at this point I can't ask more specific questions as I do not know how to. I will continue to immerse myself in more online tutorials and will return with some code! If there are any recommendations, please recommend. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right lines. You might want to set out a data structure for the guitar.

```
var guitar = {
    'colour' : 'green',
    'model' : 'gibson'
    'make' : 'example'
};
```

You can then have a drop down on the edit page for each element.

On change of any of the drop down, you update the image using the values of each data.

When the user submits, collate all the data and pass to PHP to create an order using the same data format.

JSON is useful as Javascript and PHP both have methods to encode and decode JSON data to/from arrays.

Example update function:

```
function UpdateImage()
{
    colour = document.getElementById("gColour").value;
    document.getElementById("IMG-Colour").value = colour;

    model = document.getElementById("gModel").value;
    document.getElementById("IMG-Model").value = model;

    make = document.getElementById("gMake").value;
    document.getElementById("IMG-Make").value = make;
}
```

Example submit function:

```
function SubmitOrderToPHP()
{
     colour = document.getElementById("gColour").value;
     model = document.getElementById("gModel").value;
     make = document.getElementById("gMake").value;

    url = 'order-submit.php?colour=' + colour + '&model=' + model + '&make=' + make;

    window.location = url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, much appreciated!

Comment: No problems. Good luck with your project!